# Passing variables through many activities

Tags: java, android

on `MainActivity` I have two edit texts which I get name and age values

now I have in this activity for example `name="Mohamed" age=26`

my questions is how to use these variables freely in other activities without passing them through Intent

Comment: You could use SharedPreference to save the values and retrieve them later. Or use sqlite to store the values in database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i make my app remeber/save the coins my app users earned my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246801/how-can-i-make-my-app-remeber-save-the-coins-my-app-users-earned-my-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Shared Preferences.

**Set the values:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putInt("age", age);
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve values:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredName = prefs.getString("name", null); //null is the default value.
int age = prefs.getInt("age", 0); //0 is the default value.
```

For more information visit [Android Doc Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: and the pref name what does it refer to

Comment: MY_PREFS_NAME is a string variable like String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"; It's just a name you put to the shared preferences

Comment: basically, pref name is a preferences file name that is used for storing your data. you may have user preferences belonging to particular user name and when your app switches between them, it'll pick corresponding preferences file and take the user-specific data from it. e.g. if you have user1 and user2 and will specify them as MY_PREFS_NAME, you'll end up with two shared preferences files user1.xml, user2.xml. does it make more sense? previous commenter described it as well